# Create a multidimensional array with a variable key

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array:

```
var arr = Array()
```

I wish to make this a multidimensional array, but I wish to pass in the keys dynamically.

Is there a way to do this?

```
p.addArrayKey = function(key){

    arr.key.push('something');

}
```

Comment: Could you show an example of the end result? It's not clear what you mean by "multidimensional".

Comment: They can but shouldn't

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Sure they can. After all a javascript array is just syntactic sugar surrounding an object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not really explained what you mean by "multidimensional array". Multidimensional means that your elements would need to be accessed via more than one index. Example:

```
arr[ 3, 4 ] = ...; // tells us that arr is a 2-dimensional array
arr[ 4, 5, 1 ] = ..; //.....3-dimensional array

arr[ key ] = 'something'; // is a one-dimensional array!!
```

But yes, you can use a key as an index as follows. You cannot use the `dot` notation because `key` is a variable. And since you have the index, `key`, you don't use push but you can assign the value directly:

```
arr[ key ] = 'something';
```

So that your method is:

```
p.addArrayKey = function(key, something){

    arr[ key ] = something;

};
```

And you can call it like so:

```
p.addArrayKey ( 'mykey', 'something' );
```

And the output would be:

```
[mykey: "something"]
```

[**WORKING JSFIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/6pQrX/)

However if `something` is the key you want to create in the array:

```
arr.something = 'initial value'; // or
arr[ 'something' ] = 'initial value'; //
```

Should work just fine.